# Total Reputation less than quarter reputation

Tags: discussion, support

How can One's **Total Reputation** be less than **Quarter Reputation**? I have never seen such scenario in SO but just came across one today. Below is the image of what I am talking about.

[image: Issue Image]

As of my knowledge, calculations on quarter reputation will be done along with negative reputation too. Does anyone have idea on this? I feel this as issue?

Comment: Perhaps quarter reputation is reputation gained, without taking into account bounties "paid"?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yea that is one doubt I have now..